# Jquery- Full screen popup overlay on href click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I want to show Full Screen Overlay Popup on clicking href tag. I tried a lot but couldn't find a particular solution. So far I am able to show/hide popup but i am failed to show full screen popup. So far working fiddle and necessary code is mentioned below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.opop').click(function(){
        $('.pops').fadeIn();
    });
    $('.cls-pop').click(function(){
        $('.pops').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```css
.pops{
 display:none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
     <ul>
         <li>Abc</li>
         <li>Abc</li>
         <li>Abc</li>
         <li>Abc</li>
         <li>Abc</li>
         <li>Abc</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="opop">Open Popup</a>
        
        <div class="pops">
         Some Content
            
                <ul>
                    <li>Bcd</li>
                    <li>Bcd</li>
                    <li>Bcd</li>
                    <li>Bcd</li>
                    <li>Bcd</li>
                </ul>
                
                <p> Some More Content </p>
                <a href="#" class="cls-pop">Close Popup</a>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hTQb8/128/

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ashish

```
.pops{
display:none;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ashish working fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/hTQb8/134/

**html**

```
<div class="items">
    <ul>
        <li>Abc</li>
        <li>Abc</li>
        <li>Abc</li>
        <li>Abc</li>
        <li>Abc</li>
        <li>Abc</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="opop">Open Popup</a>
</div>
<div class="pops">
        Some Content

            <ul>
                <li>Bcd</li>
                <li>Bcd</li>
                <li>Bcd</li>
                <li>Bcd</li>
                <li>Bcd</li>
            </ul>

            <p> Some More Content </p>
            <a href="#" class="cls-pop">Close Popup</a>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.pops{
    display:none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    position : absolute;
    z-index:1;
top:0;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.opop').click(function(){
    $('.pops').fadeIn();
});
$('.cls-pop').click(function(){
    $('.pops').fadeOut();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.pops{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to move your popup html out of container and inside body.

**HTML**

```
<div class="items">...</div>
<div class="pops">....</div>
```

and some changing in your css code to make it cover window with CSS main properties.

**CSS (Key properties to achieve with any kind of html):**

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
z-index:999;
```

have a look at [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hTQb8/132/)

Answer (score 0):

Easy and best way to implement modal box without using any external file..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#link').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal-overlay, #overlay-wrapper').fadeIn(500);
});
  $('#close').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal-overlay, #overlay-wrapper').fadeOut(500);
});
})
```

```css
html, body {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
#modal-overlay {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #000;
    opacity    : 0.6;
    filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index    : 5;
    display    : none;
}

#overlay-wrapper {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 10;
    display  : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="#">click me</a>
<div id="modal-overlay"></div>
<div id="overlay-wrapper">
  <a id="close" href="#">Close</a>
  <span>modal box value</span></div>
```

alue